When I open a Jupyter notebook, is there a way to automatically view the Table of Contents?
When I open a Jupyter notebook, I typically choose View > Table of Contents immediately.  Is there a way to set this in a config file so that I do not have to do this manually?
I could not find any way to save the settings for the next time that I open the notebook

This is already been asked for current Jupyter Notebooks 7+ here. There is a link to a still open issue there where you can add your input.
